# Complex separation and groupby to display percentages (Pandas/Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Dilemma:**

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to separate and groupby a complex format within a specific column and display the percentages. I am separating the values in the ***Type*** column by focusing on the first three 'words' (ex.) **Hello-HEL-HE-**  and the value followed by the letter T **-12T**

```
There are    3  unique counts    of   Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T
             2  unique counts    of   Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T
             1  unique count(s)  of   Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T
```

**Data:**

```
Type                                    Value

Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.A    1,111,111
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.B    111,111
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.E    2,345,667
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.C    222,334
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.A    89
Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T_version-v.A  6
```

**Desired output:**

```
Type                                    Percent

Hello-HEL-HE-12T                        50%
Hello-HEL-HE-50T                        33%
Happy-HAP-HA-90T                      16.6%
```

**Doing:**

(suggestion is to split on '_' and then split on '-' )

```
df.str.split(pat="_")                                      #separating by hyphen

(df['Type'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100).to_frame()  #groupby
```

However, I am not sure how to separate each Type by: Hello-HEL-HE as well as -12T

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: How do you define that `-12T` and `-90T` are portions that you are interested in?  Is it because they are two digits followed by `'T'`, or is it because they are the last bit before `'_'`?

Comment: Due to the placing- I see that they are in the '6th' place separated by hyphens

Comment: the part that's at the 5th place would be `'12T_TYPE'`...

Comment: yes @PierreD  also because it has the T at the end

Comment: Ok I see- I would separate it due to it having the 2 digit value immediately followed by  a T

Comment: `df['Type'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100).to_frame()` cannot be right, there is a missing `(`. How about splitting on `_` then splitting on `-` then combining the first three and the last string together to make a new index?

Comment: ok thank you @PaulBrennan I will try this

Comment: you mention "the first three words", but your example shows all words before the underscore...

Comment: Let me update the output please @PierreD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try

```
df=df.assign(Value=df['Value'].str.split(','),Type=df.Type.str.split('_').str[0])
df2=(df['Type'].value_counts(normalize=True)*100).to_frame('%')
df2.rename_axis(index='Type')
 



                                   %
Type                                  
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T  50.000000
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T  33.333333
Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T   16.666667
```

Comment: nice use of `value_counts`!

Comment: Ok thank you- just wondering, why would we reference the Value column when we are doing the groupings on the Type col?

Comment: Thank you @wwnde, its giving me : AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!  Do I need to convert to string?

Comment: See my edits if that helps. Its the nature of the computation that thrusts that way really.

Comment: Ok it is still saying this error- I think I need to convert that column to string since it is numeric?

Comment: It is working for me. Unless you have other columns. This is the data I used if it may help; `df=pd.DataFrame({'Type':['Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.A','Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.B','Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.E','Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.C','Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.A','Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T_version-v.A'],'Value':['1,111,111','111,111','2,345,667','222,334','89','6']})`

Comment: Just incase the exploding of `Value` is the issue. Could you try `df=df.assign(Type=df.Type.str.split('_').str[0])
df2=(df['Type'].value_counts(normalize=True)*100).to_frame('%')
print(df2.rename_axis(index='Type'))`

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
df['Type'].str.split('_').str[0].value_counts(normalize=True)

Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T    0.500000
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T    0.333333
Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T     0.166667
```

If you want that specific form then:

```
tmp = df['Type'].str.split('_').str[0].value_counts(normalize=True).reset_index(name='percentage').rename(columns={'index': 'Type'})

tmp['percentage'] = tmp['percentage'].apply(lambda x: '{:.2f}%'.format(100*x))

tmp

Type percentage
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T     50.00%
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T     33.33%
Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T     16.67%
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all fields before the underscore:

```
key = df.Type.str.split(r'_', n=1, expand=True)[0]
key

# out:
0    Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T
1    Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T
2    Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T
3    Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T
4    Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T
5     Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T
```

If instead, you'd like the first three words, and the last before the underscore, then:

```
a = df.Type.str.split(r'_', n=1, expand=True)[0].str.split(r'-', expand=True)
sel = list(a.columns)
sel = sel[1:3] + sel[-1:]
key = a[0].str.cat(a[sel], '-')
key

# out:
0    Hello-HEL-HE-12T
1    Hello-HEL-HE-12T
2    Hello-HEL-HE-12T
3    Hello-HEL-HE-50T
4    Hello-HEL-HE-50T
5    Happy-HAP-HA-90T
```

In either case, you can then groupby that key:

```
cnt = df.groupby(key)['Value'].count()
100 * cnt / cnt.sum()

# out:
Happy-HAP-HA-90T    16.666667
Hello-HEL-HE-12T    50.000000
Hello-HEL-HE-50T    33.333333
```